# Is it possible to add `ChangeDetectorRef` to the constructor of Angular 4 service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a service file that alert system of `Subjects` that when setting the value it also set itself to reset to null after 3 seconds using `setTimeout()` method. But after adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the `app.component.ts` it seem to screw up all the `SetTimeout()` method. Is there a way to use `ChangeDetectorRef` in a service?

**storage.service.ts**

```js
private errorMsg: Subject < string > = new Subject();
private successMsg: Subject < string > = new Subject();

constructor() {}

setSuccessAlert(msg: string) {
  this.successMsg.next(msg);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.successMsg.next(null);
  }, 3000);
}
```

**Without ChangeDetectionStrategy**
[image]

Comment: any specific reason you want this ? may be there are other ways

Comment: I have a service that extends the `Http` for server call intercept purposes and that throw `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.` constantly. Having ChangeDetection Strategy` stops the error. That's the only reason I need this.

Comment: this is a work around actually you should try and eliminate this error in service calls for best possible results @Praveen what value are you to change before angular grabs it

Comment: @RahulSingh I have used incrementing and decrementing number ( `0` to be `false` state) for server call cunting, Then I used boolean value itself as well and that threw the same error. I can post the Http service as well if you need it.

Comment: What does "screw up" mean exactly? A `ChangeDetectorRef` is tied to a component and can only be injected there. You can inject `AppRef` to a service AFAIR.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer All of my `setTimeout()` method aren't working now and some of them are in `service.ts` files. I tried `ApplicationRef.tick()` method in the service, but there were no effects.

Comment: I doubt the issue is that `setTimeout()` isn't working anymore, the problem is that the components don't run change detection, even with `ApplicationRef.tick()` because `OnPush` components that are not marked for check are skipped. I'd suggest you use an `Observable` in the service and subscribe to it in the components and then emit an event using the observable and in the subscriptions in components call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` or ``ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, That worked. If you could submit that answer as an actual answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt the issue is that `setTimeout()` isn't working anymore.

The problem is that the components don't run change detection, even with `ApplicationRef.tick()` because `OnPush` components that are not marked for check, are skipped.

I'd suggest you use an `Observable` in the service and subscribe to it in the components, and then emit an event using the observable and in the subscriptions in components call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`